# Internal network speed deterioration

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-server-2008, switch

I am having internal network speed issues on my network.
The Server (Windows 2008 R2) has two network cards. One provides 802.1x authentication to the outside world. The second, shares this using ICS to other devices on the internal network. The server also acts as a DNS and DHCP Server (DNS primary is set to my server, secondary is that of the external network.

All these devices are connected to a TP-Link TL-SG2109WEB Gigabit managed switch, with 80.211q VLANs – The server and Wireless AP are in both VLANS because the Wireless has multiSID VLANs.

The main problem, as soon as I power the server, the network speed immediately begins to drop within the internal network, within 5 minutes the transfer speed of anything internally is ~100kbs/s when at the beginning its over 50MB/s.

All NICs on the networks are 10/100/1000, so I know that is not the issue.

Solutions tried so far:

- Alternative unmanaged switch
- Different CAT6 cables
- Removing network devices

Any ideas anyone can throw at me would be much appreciated.

**EDIT 1** - additional info

I should have also mentioned that sometimes (often after several successive reboots of the entire "internal" network, including server) the internal netowrk works fine, with all transfers above 50MB/sec

**EDIT 2** - MTU Changes

Changing the MTU down to 800 on both server and computers failed to solve the problem.

Comment: Sounds like the server is flooding the network with traffic. Can you monitor this on your switch or install a program like peerblock to monitor traffic? Have you checked for viruses?

Comment: @Yeodave : Virus free and when you monitor the network, there is no traffic apart from standard background.
The external network connection is also idle apart from again standard background. Checked with wireshark, Just a strange lot of "TCP Segment of a reassembled PDU" between the server and a desktop

Comment: check MTUs on both links, server load (probably). Can you name used NICs?

Comment: @LazyBadger : MTU on all network connections is default (1500).
The server has 2 NIC's, one for internal, and for external (another network which provides internet but has 802.1x authentication)
All other devices have the same problem on the internal network, whether ethrenet for wireless connection.
However the external connection on the server is fine - I can go on it and download a 1GB file in just over 1 min.
NOTE: I also have (or just am about to) add an extra piece of info to the main question.

Comment: did you tried to minimize intranet and have in it only one additional host, connected to server by crossover? Did you tried to disable WAN interface on server? and yes, monitor internal speed in both cases

Comment: just to note - "In tcpdump I trust", not in wireshark. You have **not have** packets-fragmentation at all in your case on any interface

Comment: @LazyBadger: Thanks, I've changed the MTU down to 800, and followinga full system power down and restart, it is working, however it may be because sometimes it will all boot up and work fine.
I'll keep an eye on it, and post an update tomorrow after a few powercycles.

Comment: @LazyBadger, nupp, that didnt work either, unless I should take the MTU even lower?

Comment: No, lowering change nothing. Try my previous ideas with bet separation into smallest slices

Comment: @LazyBadger, nope still not getting anywhere....